# How can I run a shell script on a remote machine with a local Perl program?

Tags: perl

I'm writing a Perl script that is to be run on a PC networked with a computer running Linux. The script must give input to, and receive results from, a set of shell scripts on the Linux machine. I'm able to copy the input files from the PC and even invoke a Perl script on the Linux machine, but when that script attempts to run the .sh files via:

```
 system("./shell_script.sh");
```

It prints the following error:

```
 '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Which I take to mean it's trying to execute the .sh files under Windows. So is there any way to get the PC to tell the Linux box, "hey, buddy, run this yourself"?

Thank you.

Comment: A small bit of sample code to give some context around the system call may be useful.

Comment: Good idea, just a sec...

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH-Perl) to run the commands/scripts on remote machine:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $command = "command";
my $host = "host";
my $user = "username";
my $pass = "password";

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new( $host );
$ssh->login( $username, $pass );
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd( $command );

print $stdout;
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use something like [Net::SSH](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH) or [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Expect) to login into the Linux machine and run the shell script. The `system()` runs on the local machine; it's not a way to send commands to a remote machine.